# Rails Use models, namespaced and connected to different db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a rails 5 app, and need reporting functionality. I want to keep it in app for now, and not use a rails engine. The reporting functionality connects to a heroku follower database.

Can I copy my normal models and use them as subclasses of a parent class that connects to the follower database as follows?

```
module Reporting
 class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.abstract_class = true
   establish_connection("follower_database")
 end
end

module Reporting
  class User < Reporting::Base
    # I would like to avoid copying and pasting all the user model code here and have some fancy way for it to just inherit or included it all so when we add new associations etc. the reporting classes automatically get it..
  end
end
```

Comment: `establish_connection` is method of ActiveRecord::Base. No matter you use Rails or not, ActiveRecord::Base should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the full connection configuration to the `establish_connection` method. To share functionality of the normal User class, you can inherit from that class and include the database connection from a module  e.g.

```
module FollowerDatabaseConnection
  def self.included(base)
    base.establish_connection base.configurations['follower_database']
  end 
end

class Reporting::User < User
  include FollowerDatabaseConnection
end
```

and define connection configuration in database.yml

```
# database.yml
common:
  ...
development:
  ...
...
follower_database:
  adapter: ..
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, what Im trying to figure out is in my example how does that user class that is namespaced inherit all of the functionality from the norma user class...without copy and pasting

Comment: Edited answer to address comment.